# Can you create a wordpress cluster with Amazon Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster, amazon-cloudformation

DOes it work? Do I just need to create new machines with the same template or would it not work because they all need one SQL backend?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, however, you indeed need to ensure all web servers access the same SQL backend (high availability solutions like e.g. [read replicas](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/#Read_Replica) aside right now).

Presumably there has only been a simple single instance Wordpress template available when you asked the question, e.g. [Single EC2 Instance web server with Amazon RDS database instance](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/WordPress_Single_Instance_With_RDS.template)? This one would indeed not allow to cluster Wordpress by running it multiple times, rather you'd start separate Wordpress instances each time.

However, the list of [AWS CloudFormation Sample Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) has grown and meanwhile there is a Wordpress template for a [Highly Available Web Server with Multi-AZ Amazon RDS Instance](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/WordPress_Multi_AZ.template) available as well, which is currently configured to allow 1-5 web server instances talking to a [Multi-AZ](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/#Multi-AZ) MySQL [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) database instance and running behind an [Elastic Load Balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), which orchestrates the web server instances via [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/).